# jQuery click function fires up on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'v been trying to figure this out on my own and searched up on google but I don't know what the problem is, the click function keeps firing up on page load. Please explain the problem and how to fix it. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.menu-icon').click(function(){
       $('.menu-nav').animate({
            height: 'toggle'
          }, 200
       );
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample fiddle? The code you pasted does not explain anything

Comment: @Vatsal https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=TcR5EK07ab

Comment: Please don't give a collaboration URL. Create a Stack Snippet here on SO.

Comment: Please check this. It works as expected https://jsfiddle.net/vatsalpande/zmoko9yk/

Comment: @Vatsal The menu is open when page loads, i need it to be closed and only opened when menu-icon is clicked.

Comment: Just place `.menu-nav{display:none}` in your CSS? Like @Vatsal answered

Comment: @yuriy636 i had display none from start, now i just checked and its gone! I have no idea how i deleted it. The problem is fixed thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not firing on page load. It has to do with your css rather than javascript code. Javascript is working as expected. You need to set menu hidden when the page loads for the first time. 
Please see this

https://jsfiddle.net/vatsalpande/zmoko9yk/1/

Add

```
display:none to .menu-nav
```

Hope this helps.

Happy Learning

Vatsal

Comment: Yup my bad, i thought i had display none the whole time until now i noticed its not there.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with a on click event like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-icon', function(){
   $('.menu-nav').animate({
    height: 'toggle'
   }, 200
   );
});
```